# Can I copy a drawing figure in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, one can insert a drawing by selecting "Insert > Drawing".  Now let's say I want to make a multiple copies of same drawing.  I want to achieve it by copying one figure and pasting it in many places.  This method however, I cannot figure out how can I achieve it (or even if its possible).

## Question

Is it possible to copy single drawing object and paste it in other place so that I can obtain multiple objects of same shaped drawing figure?

## What I have tried

1. select the target object
2. "Edit > Copy" from menu
3. "Edit > Paste" from menu

This does nothing.

Answer (score 8):

1. Double click on the drawing you want to copy.  This should open the drawing window.
2. Use the mouse draw a selection box around the entire drawing.
3. Select copy from the action menu
4. Save and Close the drawing window.
5. Select "Insert drawing" from the google sheets menu
6. Select paste in the drawing window action menu.
7. Save and Close the drawing window.

This should paste an exact copy of your entire drawing into a new location on the sheet.

Comment: It doesn't work. I creates a larger drawing object with multiple original drawings in it. But if you need to assign a script to it, this won;t work

Comment: Instead copy it like he suggested, then close the drawing window, go to Insert -> Drawing and then Actions -> Paste. This will paste it into a new drawing object. Vert cumbersome, but it kinda works

Comment: This does NOT answer the OP's question, which is _"Is it possible to copy single drawing object and paste it in other place so that I can obtain multiple objects of same shaped drawing figure?"_, but it _does_ answer my question, which is, "How do I copy a drawing?", so I've upvoted it.

Comment: It does provide a way for the OP to do what they described they wanted...